# X-Frame-Options question

Tags: http

Is it valid to use

X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

in the response header **together**? Or should only either one be present?

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sjoerd I do not "want" this. This is being sent back from the server and Im just wondering if this is valid before raising an issue with the person who added these headers in.

Comment: Out of interest, which one is taking precedence? My guess would be the browser just applies the last one it receives .

Comment: @iain Thats correct, the browser just applies the last one it receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not valid and it wouldn't make logical sense, because DENY blocks everything that SAMEORIGIN does and more.

Adding both DENY and SAMEORIGIN is invalid; and even if it is accepted, it would result in ambiguity due to the two options contradicting each other on whether resources with the same origin should be allowed in a frame or not.

Comment: Any links that actually say X-Frame-Options cannot occur twice in the response header with different values?

Comment: This makes it pretty clear the header can only have one of three forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options